# Linear Connection on the Hyperbolic Plane

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections

For the upper half-plane $\mathbb{H}^2=\{x+iy\in\mathbb{C}\ \vert\ y>0\}$ equipped with the metric $g = \frac{1}{y^2}(dx^2+dy^2)$, I computed the Christoffel symbols as follows: $$\begin{align}\Gamma^1_{12}&=\Gamma^1_{12}=-\frac{1}{y}\\\Gamma^2_{11}&=\frac{1}{y}\\\Gamma^2_{22}&=-\frac{1}{y}\end{align}$$

Then using the relation between the connection matrix and the Christoffel symbols $\omega^k_j=\Gamma^k_{ij}dx^i$, I computed $$\begin{align}
\omega^1_1 &=-\frac{1}{y}dy\\
\omega^1_2 &=-\frac{1}{y}dx\\
\omega^2_1 &=\frac{1}{y}dx\\
\omega^2_2 &=-\frac{1}{y}dy
\end{align}$$
I now have two questions:

- To get the matrix $\omega$ proper, do I now need to contract an index with the metric?
- How do I actually carry out a computation of $\nabla_X(S)$ for $X\in\Gamma(T\mathbb{H}^2),\ S\in\Gamma(\xi)$? It's clear to me that I should just stick the column vector $S$ to the right of the matrix $\omega$ and multiply in the obvious way, but how do I "plug in" the vector field $X$? An example would be really helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some perplexities concerning the equation linking $\omega$ to $\Gamma$. I get
\begin{equation}
\omega^k_j(X)\partial_k = \nabla_X\partial_j = \nabla_{X^i\partial_i}\partial_j=X^i\nabla_{\partial_i}\partial_j=X^i\Gamma^k_{ij}\partial_k
\end{equation}
hence $\omega^k_j(X)=X^i\Gamma^k_{ij}$, which gives the dependence of $\omega$ from the vector field. Then the components I get are
\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{X^2}{y} & -\frac{X^1}{y} \\ \frac{X^1}{y} & -\frac{X^2}{y}
\end{bmatrix}
and if you plug in some vector field $Y=(Y^1,Y^2)$ you need to exhaust the $j$ index:
\begin{equation}
\omega(Y)=(-\frac{X^2}{y}Y^1-\frac{X^1}{y}Y^2,\frac{X^1}{y}Y^1 -\frac{X^2}{y}Y^2)
\end{equation}
I hope this is correct & helps!

Comment: This is wonderful, thank you! Just a quick question: when you wrote down the matrix $\omega$, did you contract the components that you computed with the metric? If not, is $\omega^i_j$ the $j^\mathrm{th}$ component in the $i^\mathrm{th}$ row or the $i^\mathrm{th}$ component in the $j^\mathrm{th}$ row?

Comment: @AnthonyBritto the first one! but I don't think that it really matters, as long as you are coherent when you plug in the field (in this case, you feed it to the matrix vertically, in the other case orizontally). In any case, it's the j index which must be killed (I think)