# The Levi-Civita Connection on the Hyperbolic Plane

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1649014/linear-connection-on-the-hyperbolic-plane) question here, I asked about computing the Levi-Civita connection matrix on the Hyperbolic Plane, defined as $\mathbb{H}^2=\{x+iy\in\mathbb{C}\ \vert\ y>0\}$ equipped with the metric $g = \frac{1}{y^2}(dx^2+dy^2)$. The answer (which I believe is correct) was given as: $$\omega^i_j(X)=\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{X^2}{y} & -\frac{X^1}{y} \\ \frac{X^1}{y} & -\frac{X^2}{y}
\end{bmatrix}\ .$$

But I have a proposition in my notes which reads:

> Let $\xi$ be a smooth vector bundle equipped with an inner product $<\cdot ,\cdot>$ and a connection $\nabla$. Then $\nabla$ is compatible with the inner product if and only if in any local orthonormal frame $(s_i)$ the connection matrix $\omega$ is skew-symmetric.

The matrix $\omega$ above is clearly not skew-symmetric, and I'm not quite sure what to make of this apparent contradiction. It is certainly not true that there exists no Levi-Civita connection on the hyperbolic plane, so where am I going wrong?

Comment: Note that you have the connection matrix of a manifold and not of a connection on a vector bundle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the proposition you quoted says, the connection forms have to be skew-symmetric with respect to any *orthonormal* frame. You computed the connection forms with respect to the coordinate frame $\{\partial/\partial x, \partial/\partial y\}$, which is not orthonormal for the hyperbolic metric.